# Combined TableViews & CollectionViews in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am stuck...
I have a collectionView (let's call it `masterCollectionView`).  Each cell of the collectionView holds a list of data.

In each of these collectionView cells in the `masterCollectionView`, I have a tableView which holds all the records themselves in each row, grouped into tableView sections based on certain criteria within the dataset.

The data is stored in a multi-dimensional array which I download from the cloud, and this provides the list title to the `masterCollectionView` cell, as well as the # of sections, # of records (i.e. rows) in each list for the respective tableView.

My problem is that I can't tell which `masterCollectionView` cell I'm in when I'm populating the tableView.  For example:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
}
```

The above function doesn't allow me to identify the `masterCollectionView` cell I'm currently building the tableView in and therefore I don't know which records in the data array to load.

At the moment I have all of the above built as one storyboard in interface builder along with one corresponding viewController but can easily change based on recommendations.

Please help.  I'm pulling my hair out.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Why don't you just create a generic tableView class and then in each collectionViewCell initialize the tableView and pass it the necessary data?

Comment: At the moment, I have it all in one view controller.  Every tableView is getting populated with the same data in each collectionView cell because it doesn't know which part of the data array to get that specific tableview's data.  How would I go about doing what you're suggesting?  I think what you're saying is probably what I need to do just not sure I know how to go about it.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: But if you want to get each tableView to know what collectionViewCell it is inside, you knees to separate it out into two classes. For the tableViews, create an abstract subclass of UITableView

Comment: Thanks.  I'm new to swift and iOS dev.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to have a separate instance of your table view data source for each collection view cell.

You could create a new NSObject subclass implementing UITableViewDataSource whose purpose is only to act as the data source for one cell. This object can be configured with the data for that cell only.

You would then have an array of these instances, one for each collection view cell. When the cell is loaded in cellForItemAtIndexPath, set that cell's table view delegate to the correct data source from the array.

Comment: Thanks Angela.  How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I will first give you the quickest solution to your problem, although its easy to implement it is not the 'right' way to do it I will explain later.

So the quickest way to do it is using view tags. Each `UIView` has a tag member which is an Integer. So where ever you are setting your tables, you can do this

I dont have your code so I am assuming you setting your table in

`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell`

function of your `UICollectionView`, so in there you do something like this

```
myTableView.tag = indexPath.row
```

This should set tag to the TableView, when you are creating them which would be index in the array. and in your `UITableView` datasource you can do this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return yourDataArray[tableView.tag].count;
}
```

This is the short and quick way the correct way would be to break up your data properly, may your `UICollectionView` cells as datasources for the included `UITableView` and then load the data when needed.

Comment: The correct solution is exactly what @Angela above is telling you about